# I keep seeing +--+ in my apache logs, what is it?

Tags: apache, security

I am looking at my apache server logs and almost always when someone is scanning the server for vulnerabilities I always see this in their query strings...

+--+

like in the various examples below...

```
.
.
.
/includes/usercp_register.php?phpbb_root_path=1&#39;+--+?
/includes/profilcp_constants.php?module_root_path=1&#39;+--+?
/includes/functions_user_viewed_posts.php?phpbb_root_path=1&#39;+--+?
/includes/orderSuccess.inc.php?&glob=1&cart_order_id=1&glob[rootDir]=1&#39;+--+
.
.
.
```

I know they are scanning for popular vulnerabilities but what Im wondering is whats the purpose of +--+?

Im thinking of using that as something I can filter for using fail2ban

Answer (score 6):

In query strings, the plus character is shorthand notation for a space.  Remember that spaces are not allowed in URLs, so they must either be percent-encoded (`%20`) or, *only in the query string portion of a URL*, represented with a plus.  (As a consequence, this means actual pluses must be percent-encoded in the query string but not elsewhere in a URL.)

In this case, the attacker is attempting simple [SQL injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/10974/4906).  The `&#39;` is a quote (`'`), and the `+` URL-decodes to a space.  So ultimately this happens:

```
phpbb_root_path=1' --
```

(The `--` is a SQL comment.)

Be careful banning requests with `+--+` in the URL; that could be legitimate input -- ie, https://www.google.com/search?q=dash+--+separated

Comment: +1 If I would have known this was so simple, I wouldn't have voted to move this to superuser!

Comment: Thanks! looks like "=1&#39;+--+" would be a better filter